# Perforce error - warning: cannot submit from non-stream client-Title

Tags: perforce

Perforce error - warning: cannot submit from non-stream client- Body
//abc/efg/FNO/src/com/hij/klm/web/actions/struts2/File1.java - warning: cannot submit from non-stream client
No files to submit.
Submit failed -- fix problems above then use 'p4 submit -e 278742'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that P4V has guided you to create a stream depot and a mainline, but has somehow created a non-stream workspace for you. From what I've heard, that's likely to happen for first-time P4V users due to something in the setup.
To see if that's the problem, go to ---->Connection/Edit Workspace and look in the 'Stream' field. Is it empty? If so, use Browse to select the stream. This will turn your current workspace into a stream workspace.
Refer the below screen:
[image]